# How to install Google play service?

Tags: android

In my sdk manager I navigate the extras tab, but there is no **Google play service** package. What to do ?

Comment: I miss the "insufficient information" close reason... Now I am never sure what to do with questions like this...

Comment: @XaverKapeller "Unclear what you're asking" is covering this problem fine.

Comment: @XaverKapeller wouldnt that be the `unclear what you are asking` option?

Comment: @tyczj Yes I realise that, but is it really unclear what he is asking?   He wants to use the Google Play Services library, but cannot find it in the SDK manager. I wouldn't think of this as unclear. I now that this close reason covers questions like this, I just think the wording doesn't fit at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First update to the latest Android (4.4 or something) The extra's will update accordingly and you can download it.